# How to reconstruct Image from patches in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have extracted 8x8 patches from an Image of size (512x512).
I want to reconstruct the Image from those patches. Like in Python(scikit-learn lib) there has an function named `reconstruct_from_patches_2d(patches, image_size)` which helps to reconstruct the image from patches.

is there have any function like that in Matlab??

Comment: do those patches overlap? if not you could simply concatenate them.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html

Comment: yes, patches are overlaped  @Piglet

Comment: Can't you calculate the overlap, remove the overlap and then concatenate the patches?